# Capybara.page not in scope after extending capybara-screenshot's after_failed_example method

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to override the after_failed_example method so I can inflict some custom file naming on our screenshots. I'm loading the module as an initializer.

So far, so good, but the Capybara.page.current_url is blank, making me think I need to require something additional?

```
require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"
module Capybara
  module Screenshot
    module RSpec

      class << self
        attr_accessor :use_description_as_filename
        attr_accessor :save_html_file
      end

      self.use_description_as_filename = true
      self.save_html_file = true

      def self.after_failed_example(example)
        if example.example_group.include?(Capybara::DSL) # Capybara DSL method has been included for a feature we can snapshot
          Capybara.using_session(Capybara::Screenshot.final_session_name) do
            puts ">>>> Capybara.page.current_url: " + Capybara.page.current_url.to_s
            if Capybara::Screenshot.autosave_on_failure && failed?(example) && Capybara.page.current_url != ''
              saver = Capybara::Screenshot.new_saver(Capybara, Capybara.page, Capybara::Screenshot.save_html_file?, set_saver_filename_prefix(example))
              saver.save
              example.metadata[:screenshot] = {}
              example.metadata[:screenshot][:html]  = saver.html_path if saver.html_saved?
              example.metadata[:screenshot][:image] = saver.screenshot_path if saver.screenshot_saved?
            end
          end
      end

      private

        def self.set_saver_filename_prefix(example)
          return example.description.to_s.gsub(" ", "-") if Capybara::Screenshot.use_description_as_filename?
          return Capybara::Screenshot.filename_prefix_for(:rspec, example)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is successfully overriding the capybara-screenshot/rspec method, and any of the Capybara::Screenshot static information is accessible, but not Capybara session related information (afa I can tell).

For example, Capybara.page.current_url.to_s is null when overridden, but present when not.

Answer (score 0):

I *was* missing a require (kind of silly mistake):

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```